# Converting total time in integer into HH:MM format in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using below given formula to change 3.50 hours to 03:30(HH:MM) format in crystal report but it showing 04:30(1 hr added automatically)

```
numbervar totalHours:=ToNumber({Table.ExtraHoursOn1});
numbervar totalminutes:=ToNumber({Table.ExtraHoursOn1})*60 mod 60;
ToText(totalHours,0)+':'+
ToText(totalminutes,'00')
```

I don't know where i am getting wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right syntax for changing the format, truncate function was missing

```
numbervar totalHours:=ToNumber({Table.ExtraHoursOn1});
numbervar totalminutes:=ToNumber({Table.ExtraHoursOn1})*60 mod 60;
ToText(Truncate(totalHours),0)+':'+
ToText(totalminutes,'00')
```

Comment: Also, you can do it without variables. I had just a minutes feld, and did it this way: `ToText(Truncate({NumberInMinutes}/60),0)+':'+ToText({NumberI‌​nMinutes} mod 60,'00') `