# Crystal Reports 8 how to pass minutes to hh:mm

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a field on my BD (Called `Minutes`) and it counts the total time. I need to show it as hh:mm and I made this function that works perfectly but I'm so sure that there is a fastest and easier way to get the same result... do you know how can i make it? I've tried with `time()` and some tries with `totext()` but nothing works...  Also saw [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702959/converting-total-time-in-integer-into-hhmm-format-in-crystal-report) but it writes 4:08 for example instead of 04:08

```
 if Truncate(REMAINDER({TABLE.MINUTES},60))<10 then //if hour<10
       if len(TOTEXT(TRUNCATE((({TABLE.MINUTES}) MOD 60)/10),0) )>0 then //if minutes >9
            "0" + TOTEXT(Truncate ({TABLE.MINUTES}/60),0)+" : "+ TOTEXT(TRUNCATE((({TABLE.MINUTES}) MOD 60)/10),0) & TOTEXT((({TABLE.MINUTES}) MOD 60) MOD 10,0)
        else 
            "0" + TOTEXT(Truncate ({TABLE.MINUTES}/60),0)+" : 0"+  TOTEXT((({TABLE.MINUTES}) MOD 60) MOD 10,0)
    else
        if len(TOTEXT(TRUNCATE((({TABLE.MINUTES}) MOD 60)/10),0) )>0 then 
            TOTEXT(Truncate ({TABLE.MINUTES}/60),0)+" : "+ TOTEXT(TRUNCATE((({TABLE.MINUTES}) MOD 60)/10),0) & TOTEXT((({TABLE.MINUTES}) MOD 60) MOD 10,0)
        else 
            TOTEXT(Truncate ({TABLE.MINUTES}/60),0)+" : 0"+  TOTEXT((({TABLE.MINUTES}) MOD 60) MOD 10,0)
```

Some examples of what I need:

- Data in `Minutes`: 09 --> Result should be: 00:09
- Data in `Minutes`: 50 --> Result should be: 00:50
- Data in `Minutes`: 60 --> Result should be: 01:00
- Data in `Minutes`: 65 --> Result should be: 01:05
- Data in `Minutes`: 605 --> Result should be: 10:05

Thank you so much

Comment: no one knows a better way??

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (in Crystal Syntax)

```
if(Truncate({TABLE.MINUTES}/60) < 10) then
    ToText(Truncate({TABLE.MINUTES}/60),"00")+" : " +ToText(Remainder({TABLE.MINUTES},60),"00")
```